# How can I scrape data from a website?

Tags: web, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I want to scrape only four data items from the following page in each and every product from the following link that was an infinitive scroll down page.

1. name of the product
2. price of the product
3. href of the product
4. img src of the product.

All the data will be stored in a single csv file.

How can I do this?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

i have not sure of this method.
get the original source code where you can get all of info of the website including the photo link or any word

Answer (score 0):

This is usually considered a bad idea. If you write code to scrape a website for it's content, what happens when they change their markup? Or what happens when they realize you're scraping (stealing) their original content and ban your server's IP address or IP range even. It's a losing battle, so unless you have permission from them to do so I wouldn't recommend trying. It may work for a little while, but probably not for long. It's generally considered poor form to do something like this, so personally I wouldn't encourage anyone to teach someone how to scrape a website for it's content.

Furthermore, it says very clearly in their Terms of Use not to do exactly that:

```
You agree not to access (or attempt to access) the Website and the materials 
or Services by any means other than through the interface that is provided by 
Snapdeal. You shall not use any deep-link, robot, spider or other automatic 
device, program, algorithm or methodology, or any similar or equivalent manual 
process, to access, acquire, copy or monitor any portion of the Website or 
Content (as defined below), or in any way reproduce or circumvent the 
navigational structure or presentation of the Website, materials or any 
Content, to obtain or attempt to obtain any materials, documents or 
information through any means not specifically made available through the 
Website.
```